# Make a part of script run after another

Tags: php

i have a problem.
I have a script, that sends files to email after N time(executed from crontab)
The problem is, that i try to make an output from maillog to mysql.

here is a script

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Chisinau");
$faxdir = '/var/spool/fax/';
$dir = opendir("/var/spool/fax/");
while(($file = readdir($dir)) !== false){
if (($file != ".") && ($file != "..")){
    $mytime = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
    $sendfile = $file;
    $findcaller = explode('_', $file);
    $findcaller = explode('-', $file);
    $findsrc = shell_exec('echo "'.$findcaller[0].'" | sed "s/[^_]*\_//"');
    $findsrc = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),"",$findsrc);
    $caller = shell_exec('echo "'.$findcaller[1].'" | sed "s/[^_]*\_//"');
    $cutbillid = shell_exec('echo "'.$file.'" | sed "s/[^_]*\_//"');
    $findnumber = shell_exec('echo "'.$cutbillid.'" | sed "s/[^-]*\-//"');
    $findnumber=str_replace(array("\r","\n"),"",$findnumber);
    $key = '.TIF';
    $number=preg_replace('/'.$key.'.*/','',$findnumber);
    $showstatus = shell_exec('/usr/sbin/lsof | grep "'.$faxdir.'"*"'.$number.'"');

    if ($showstatus <> ""){
        exit(0);
    }else{
        $db_link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") 
            or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("centrexdb");
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT `fax2email` FROM users WHERE username='".$number."' AND faxstatus='1'");
        $fax2email = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        if ($fax2email[0] == ''){
            $currdate = shell_exec('echo "'. date('Y-m-d_H:i:s') .'"');
    $noemail = shell_exec('mv /var/spool/fax/"'.$file.'" /var/spool/fax-nomail/"'.$currdate.'"--"'.$file.'"');
        } else {
            $findcaller = explode('_', $file);
            $findcaller = explode('-', $file);
            $caller = shell_exec('echo "'.$findcaller[1].'" | sed "s/[^_]*\_//"');
            $caller=str_replace(array("\r","\n"),"",$caller);
$sendmail = shell_exec('echo | mutt -a "'.$faxdir.'""'.$sendfile.'" -s "Fax From '.$findsrc.' to '.$number.'" "'.$fax2email[0].'"');
echo "executing";
        unlink(''.$faxdir.''.$sendfile.'');
        }
        mysql_close($db_link);
    }
}
sleep(45);
$dbnew = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")
or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("FAX");
$myresult=shell_exec('cat /var/log/maillog |grep "to=<'.$fax2email[0].'>" |tail -n1');
echo $myresult;
$currentdate = shell_exec('echo "'. date('Y-m-d_H:i:s') .'"');
$umail = $fax2email[0];
mysql_query("INSERT into faxlog (Date, UserNumber, SourceNumber, UsedEmail, MailLog)     VALUES('$mytime', '$number', '$findsrc',
'$umail', '$myresult')");
mysql_close($dbnew);
sleep(5);
}

exit(0);
?>
```

The problem is that if in folder are more than 1 file, for first file script returns from log past value because the log needs a time to be written. I done tail -f /var/log/maillog and i have found that mail command executes after a 45s delay. As i understand i need to run main block with file sending and after a delay(for log to be written) get the log content.
So how can i do it?

Comment: [`sleep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)

Comment: He is already using sleep and using it will not sufice. What if the operation suddenly takes 50sec instead of 45 ?

Comment: Is there any way to determine when the action is done ?

Comment: It works! 30 seconds and block with second mysql must be after closing first mysql connection.Thanks!